# Installing memcache on windows azure

Tags: php, windows, codeigniter, azure

I want to install and use memcache in my website. Web site is running on windows azure server with `php 5.4`. I have added `PHP_EXTENSIONS` called `memcache.dll` on azure config section. I followed [THIS](http://www.phpcmsframework.com/2013/11/steps-to-implement-memcache-in.html) tutorial:

[image]

The problem is, How will I run `memcached.exe` file on windows azure?
Do you guys have any better solution to just create a basic memcache thing on website?

PS: I am using codeigniter framework in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Kudu Site Admin Tools Extensions on your website (new portal) then browse to the site admin - `https://<your-site>.scm.azurewebsites.net/`.  Choose Debug Console >> CMD.  You now have an insulated command prompt into your website and should be able to run your exe.